# How to let View Model know about successfully validated form

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, prism

I have a registration form with few fields. It´s a `PRISM MVVM` application.

XAML of one of the field looks like this (RegisterView.xaml):

```
<TextBlock>Surname</TextBlock>
<TextBox Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationTemplate}"      HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0" Name="Surname" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="Surname" UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus" >
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                 <val:Required />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

As you can see from the code above, I use class Required to validate the field. Function Validate() of class Required then returns `ValidationResult` object. I also defined some triggers to styles for inputs, so I´m able to show validation result to the user in view.

What I don't know is how to detect the state of validation of all the inputs in ViewModel. In the ViewModel, I have the `SaveUserCanExecute` function which should enable/disable registration form submit button on the basic on a validation state of all the inputs.

So is there any simple way how to achieve this?

I could make some workaround for this, but I think is not the proper way.

Now I made a Submit_Click function in a View code behind fired on a Click event of a Submit Button.

In RegisterView.xaml

```
<Button Content="Register" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0" Name="Submit" VerticalAlignment="Top" Command="{x:Static inf:Commands.SaveUser}" Click="Submit_Click" />
```

I also created new public boolean variable "formIsValid" in code behind. When submit button is pressed, then I check whether all inputs has no validation error (with `Validation.GetHasError(InputName)` function). If so, I set the `formIsValid` variable to true, otherwise, I set it to false.

In RegisterView.xaml.cs

```
private void Submit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Validation.GetHasError(Firstname) == false && Validation.GetHasError(Surname) == false)
    {
        registerFormValid = true;
    }
    else
    {
        registerFormValid = false;
    }
}
```

Then in ViewModel `SaveUserCanExecute` function looks like this:

```
private bool SaveUserCanExecute(string parameter)
{
    if (View.registerFormValid == true)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

But as I mentioned before, I think it´s not the proper way, and I´m looking for some more clear way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

implement IDataErrorInfo in your ViewModel then you have all information you need in your VM. Your XAML just need the ValidatesOnDataErrors=true

```
<TextBlock>Surname</TextBlock>
<TextBox Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationTemplate}"      HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0" Name="Surname" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding Path="Surname" UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True">
            </Binding>
        </TextBox.Text>
 </TextBox>
```

EDIT: check the use of DelegeCommand and then your command CanExecute can simply check then for string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Error).

Comment: Ok, sounds good, but how to implement IDataErrorInfo properly to return the result of validation? I checked a lot of IDataErrorInfo examples and almost in all they put some validation functions to  public string this[string propertyName] { validation functions here }. But I don´t want that since I already binded validation functions to xaml element with <Binding.ValidationRules> and I don´t want to call same function twice. Thanks.

Comment: And if I call MessageBox.Show(this.Error); in my code, then it shows nothing, even message box is not shown.

Answer (score 0):

Bind a command (ICommand) to your Submit Button and implement this logic in Its CanExecute method. Here is a classic [ICommand](http://snipplr.com/view/13642/) implementation.

Comment: This is what I did in a bit different way. I have bind composite command to my submit button (see Command="{x:Static inf:Commands.SaveUser}"). The problem is, that it´s CanExecute function is in ViewModel, so that´s why I need to get there information about validation of all inputs. Or I didn´t get your answer. Thanks anyway.

Comment: When you construct an ICommand object you give both Execute and CanExecute changed. This is done at the viewmodel level hence you can pass in your existing method. WPF will automatically call CanExecute when any input element focus changes.